# Site Sharing settings with PowerShell, PnP PowerShell or Graph API

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell, site-settings, sharing, graph-api

I'm looking for a solution to access the following setting with PowerShell, PnP PowerShell or Graph API. I can't find any option to do that. I found the option to disable it, but not to restrict it.

With `DisableSharingForNonOwners` it also breaks the file sharing option.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this already?  https://sharepoint-tricks.com/configure-sharing-on-your-sharepoint-site/

Answer (score 0):

unfortunally it doesn't work, it set the setting to "Only site owners can share files,folders and the site."